Wouldn't gay marriage bans violate the 14th amendment?
So I came across this guy saying:

Indeed. Obergefell was particularly egregious as it had the effect of disenfranchising several states. If memory serves, several states had just voted to reaffirm a ban on rainbow marriage in the months prior to Obergfell being handed down. Those voters had their voices ignored. SCOTUS making these sweeping rulings on such subjects was revolting. Obergefell needs to be overturned and the states allowed to decide for themselves.

But I think this violates the 14th amendment, specifically:

No State shall make or enforce any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens of the United States

And considering all the privileges afford to married couples...
See where I am coming from?

As the quote in the answer below explains, the "privileges and immunities" clause of the 14th Amendment is not the provision of the 14th Amendment that was violated. This is basically because marriage is not a privilege you have because you are a citizen of the United States. See the Slaughter-House Cases. https://www.oyez.org/cases/1850-1900/83us36

The original quote is saying that SCOTUS should overturn its previous ruling. If it does that then, by definition, it would not violate the 14th amendment because SCOTUS decides how to interpret the constitution.

In the opinion, Justice Kennedy wrote (emphasis mine):

These considerations lead to the conclusion that the right to marry is a fundamental right inherent in the liberty of the person, and under the Due Process and Equal Protection Clauses of the Fourteenth Amendment couples of the same-sex [sic] may not be deprived of that right and that liberty. The Court now holds that same-sex couples may exercise the fundamental right to marry. No  longer may this liberty be denied to them. Baker v. Nelson must be and now is overruled, and the State laws challenged by Petitioners in these cases are now held invalid to the extent they exclude same-sex couples from civil marriage on the same terms and conditions as opposite-sex couples.


Alot of Conservatives dont marriage in of itself as a right, then again marriage benefits fall under prvlidges and immunities no?

@JacobBlaustein No. The privileges and immunities clause of the 14th Amendment applies to the privileges and immunities you have because you are a United States citizen. The legal right to marry is not dependent upon citizenship.
